# How to filter in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'm learning XSLT and am practicing on trying to filter an existing XML file, and basically copy the tree with only selected nodes of interest - if they have match the condition say having the substring 'test'.

Using the identity transform pattern, I have the following snippet:

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="(node() |  @*)[contains(name(.), 'test')]" />

<!-- Bonus Q: What would be happening behind the scenes when I put this code inside the copy element?
<xsl:value-of select="." /> -->

    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Now this gets me the following output,

```
<head>
<testA> <testAChild /></testA> <!-- should be <testA> <testAChild> foo </testAChild></testA> -->
<testB /> <!-- should be <testB> bar </testB> -->
<Ctest /> <!-- should be <Ctest> foobar </Ctest> -->
          <!-- should be <DontDeleteThis> <testD> 420 </testD></DontDeleteThis> -->
</head>
```

However, it doesn't have the values in the resulting tree. Furthermore, it isn't checking every case when the current node is false but the child, grandchildren, or possibly grand grand children could pass the criteria.

Here is an example of the input XML:

```
<head>
    <testA>
        <testAChild> foo </testAChild>
    </testA>
    <testB> bar </testB>
    <Ctest> foobar </Ctest>
    <DeleteThis> DELETED </DeleteThis>
    <DontDeleteThis>
        <testD>  420 </testD>
    </DontDeleteThis>
</head>
```

Comment: Please provide your XML file also.

Comment: @AntonH I edited the question, and updated with a XML snippet. I'm looking for a generic solution to this kind of problem, so it should be flexible enough to work on other kinds of XML structure too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match on ancestor element names, descendant element names, and descendant processing instruction names, you have to do so explicitly. Your code is only examining the name of the current node. And if you want to match on attribute names, you need to make sure the element the attribute is attached to can't be discarded. For example:

```
<transform xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xml:lang="en-latn">
    <output media-type="application/xml"/>
    <template match="attribute::node() | child::node()">
        <copy>
            <variable name="attributes" select="attribute::node()[contains(name(), 'test')]"/>
            <variable name="elements" select="child::*[count((descendant-or-self::node() | attribute::node())[contains(name(), 'test')]) > 0]"/>
            <variable name="comments" select="child::comment()[count(ancestor::node()[contains(name(), 'test')]) > 0]"/>
            <variable name="PIs" select="child::processing-instruction()[count(ancestor-or-self::node()[contains(name(), 'test')]) > 0]"/>
            <variable name="text" select="child::text()[count(ancestor::node()[contains(name(), 'test')]) > 0]"/>
            <apply-templates select="$attributes | $elements | $comments | $PIs | $text"/>
        </copy>
    </template>
</transform>
```

Also worth noting that Rupesh's code will not match on processing instruction (PI) node names. There's a subtle difference between `*` and `node()`; `*` is shorthand for element nodes except on the `attribute` and `namespace` axes, which means that you must use `node()` to match PI nodes. (In XPath 2, there's a corresponding longhand for `*` in `element()`/`element(*)`. I think knowing that makes this concept a bit less confusing.)

As for your bonus question, the `value-of` element runs the `string` XPath function on selected nodes. So for all matched elements, the string value of the element (i.e., all its text nodes concatenated) will be output at the location of the `value-of` element. For matched attribute, comment, processing instruction, and text nodes, no additional text will be output since the `copy` element ignores its content for those node types.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
    <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[descendant-or-self::*[contains(name(.), 'test')]]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()[contains(name(.), 'test')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

it will give your desire output